# buffered store with local sorting (client-side)

Tags: sorting, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a buffered grid on which I've implemented a local sort function (client side). I would like to remove the sort indication (darker background and little arrow) on the column header when the store reloads.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this in 4.1?

**To make this clearer:**

I **want** my columns to be sortable. I do not want them to initialize with sorting disabled. Users should be able to click the header and sort it all they want. *But*, what I want is to be able to turn off the sort programmatically. I.e., remove any sort classes that were applied from user clicks (things like the darker background and the little sort direction arrow).

The reason I would do this is because I am using a modified buffered store which allows me to do local sorting (client-side) with all of the buffered data (not just the chunk that is displayed). Normally, using a buffered store will make local sorting disabled because it would only sort the data that is displayed in the grid - not all of the data in memory, so the guys at Sencha made any grid that has a buffered store automatically disable local sorting - only remote sorting works. Well, as I said, mine is modified so it will work - but then when this buffered store reloads with new data from the database it does not enjoy the handy `sortOnLoad` feature normal grids get as a matter of course. In my use-case it is more logical to remove the sort state than it is to override the `sortOnLoading` functionality and make it apply the same sort to the new data, hence, this question.

I do have it worked out now, I'll post an answer shortly along with my implementation of a buffered store with *local* sorting, in case anyone is interested and for my own future reference.

I should also point out that I am very aware of the client-side performance penalties that come with local sorting on a store that would need to be buffered (as opposed to just using remote sorting of the data on the server). [I am aware that this is probably why Sencha does not support local sorting on their buffered stores](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?179809-Buffered-Scrolling-Grid-example-and-sort-bug&p=746973&viewfull=1#post746973). I have assessed all of the pros and cons to this and in my specific use-case it is the most sensible thing for me to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buried deep in the dom there is a `setSortState` function on the `Ext.grid.header.Container` class and on the `Ext.grid.column.Column` class. These don't show up anywhere in the 4.1.0 docs but they're in the code nevertheless.

You can look at these functions yourself to get a complete concept of what they do, but the gist of both them is a switch statement that looks for either a `'DESC'`, `'ASC'` or a `null` in the first argument, e.g.:

```
setSortState(`DESC`);
setSortState(`ASC`);
setSortState(null);
```

Calling either the header version or the column version of this function with a single `null` argument will remove the sort classes on a column. The only real difference is that the header version looks at the grid's store to find the active sorter in the store's `sorters` property and then uses that data to determine which column to call this function on - the column version simply runs off the column object that it is called from.

In my use-case I don't add a sorter to the store `sorters` property so I am using the column version (i.e. calling `setSortState` from an `Ext.grid.column.Column` object).

First, here is an example of my implementation of a buffered store that allows local (client-side) sorting:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.TheBufferedStoreWithLocalSorting', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy',
        'Ext.util.MixedCollection'
    ],
    model: 'MyApp.model.SomeModel',
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 100,
    remoteSort: true, // this just keeps sorting from being disabled
    proxy: {
        type: 'pagingmemory',
        reader: 'json'
    },
    /* 
     * Custom sort function that overrides the normal store sort function.
     * Basically this pulls all the buffered data into a MixedCollection
     * and applies the sort to that, then it puts the SORTED data back
     * into the buffered store.               
     */                    
    sort: function(sorters) {
        var collection = new Ext.util.MixedCollection();

        collection.addAll(this.proxy.data);
        collection.sort(sorters);
        this.pageMap.clear();
        this.getProxy().data = collection.getRange();
        this.load();

    }
});
```

Now, to answer my question, to remove the sorter classes whenever the store reloads I just need to do this:

```
Ext.each(myGrid.columns, function(column, index) {
    if (column.hasCls('x-column-header-sort-ASC') ||
        column.hasCls('x-column-header-sort-DESC')) {
        myGrid.columns[index].setSortState(null);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, setting this config  on the specified column should solve your problem

```
columns: [
    {text: 'First Name',  dataIndex:'firstname', sortable: false},
    {text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex:'lastname'},
 ]
```

more details here http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-sortable

This is a configuration option, so it would disable the sortability of a column when the grid is first rendered.

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep122/McG4W/)

* Note that I use Ext. 4.0.7, you can switch to 4.1.0, but for some reason an unrelated display bug with the dropdown pops out

Comment: realised that, although this approach disables sorting for a particular column, it would not hide the  sort arrow image from the header

Comment: I clarified my clarification :) Also, I have this worked out now, I'll post my answer in a moment.

Comment: thanks for the clear clarification :), I got it all wrong then. Will be waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

When the store is reloaded you could add the following to the store's load event handler:

```
Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {

    listeners: {
        load: {
            fn: function () {
                grid.addCls("no-sort-icon");
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then modify your css to hide the icon when element is child of "no-sort-icon" (this would be on the grid)

```
.no-sort-icon .x-column-header-text {
    background-image: none;
}
.no-sort-icon .x-column-header {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}
```